# Select files reading names from a text file

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I have a directory of files. I want to select some of them based on a text file I have. The text file has partial names of the files which I need to select.

I tried using find

`ls | while read -r line; do find -type f -name $line; done < ../src_pdm3012/good_G20P1.txt`

I also tried using grep for it does not seem to work.

Comment: what is the use of `ls` there? and how does your filenames, and that text file's content look like? Can you edit your question to add examples and more details?

Comment: If the text file has _partial_ names then I think you should use `-name "*$line*"` Also you don't need `ls` here

Comment: `while read -r line; do find -type f -name *$line*; done < ../src_pdm3012/good_G20P1.txt ` This gives: 
`find: paths must precede expression: G20P1sc-C05-R2.fastq.gz
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
find: paths must precede expression: G20P1sc-C08-R2.fastq.gz
` The error message worries me. But I think it selects the files nonetheless. How do I copy these files to another location ? `| cp ` does not work

Comment: Add dot (current directory) or other directory after `find` - this is what this error means

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your comment. I have tried versions of find uses and as u can guess I dont get anything with `find.` For example `while read -r line; do find. -type f -name *$line*; done < ../src_pdm3012/good_G20P1.txt 
bash: find.: command not found` . Is there something I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Also, any idea how to copy those files ?

Comment: Just wanted to share the `find .` does give the same error as without the period. But thanks for your help and advice [i am learning as I go here]

Comment: @MichaelO. This is GNU find, so no need to add "." as a path. "paths must precede expression" means that `*$line*` should be quoted => `... -name "*$line*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since names are partial, you must find files with a name that contains the line you read, not a name that equals it:

```
while read -r line; do find -type f -name "*$line*"; done < ../src_pdm3012/good_G20P1.txt
```

Since you wanted to use `grep`, here is what you were looking for:

```
ls -a | grep -F -f ../src_pdm3012/good_G20P1.txt
```

... but keep in mind it is not a good practice to grep `ls` output

Comment: Thank you @xhienne. This helped me copy the files in the next step.